# SSIS Foreach Loop Container - Catch a script that hangs

Tags: ssis, httpwebrequest, foreach-loop-container

I have an SSIS foreach loop container that uses httpconneciton manager to download images from a webservice.

However if the image is not available there is no error, or timeout. The script process just hangs forever on that request writing a zero length file. There is no error to catch.

```
Dim connection As New HttpClientConnection(nativeObject)
    connection.ServerURL = InputFile  ' http://wwww.example.com/image?id=12345

    Try
            connection.DownloadFile(DestinationFile, True)
            Dim info As New FileInfo(DestinationFile)

            If File.Exists(DestinationFile) = False Or info.Length = 0 Then
                Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure
                Return
            End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure
    End Try
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
```

Can anybody figure out how to fail this step so I can continue the loop.

Comment: I guess it is hanging on the `connection.DownloadFile` call - you need to research this function and find out why it is doing this? This has more to do with `HttpClientConnection` than SSIS.

Comment: Just to be pedantic @ElectricLlama [HttpClientConnection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.httpclientconnection.aspx) is SSIS-related since it inherits from DtsObject

Comment: Is there any chance you've slimmed down the code to what is provided? Specifically, have you set the `Timeout` property to 0?

Comment: Not pedantic at all - I stand corrected :) No one (including me) should post anything unless they are certain about it. I'm just suprised there is a special DTS class for something as generic as HTTP communication.

Comment: @billinkc This is the bones of the script. Tinmeout is set to 0, but as I said it doesn't timeout. It seems the connection remains although no file is downloaded.  It is most definitely hanging in the connection.downloadfile call. If I had control of the webservice I could get it to throw and error.

Comment: Could you call [DownloadData](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.httpclientconnection.downloaddata.aspx) or [OpenRead](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.httpclientconnection.openread.aspx) and inspect the file first?

Comment: The MS info on the timeout property doesn't mention much, but normally Timeout=0 means 'wait forever'. So why don't you try a timeout of 30 or something, and then I would expect it should timeout after 30 seconds (and throw a timeout error). If you had posted the full code showing the timeout setting this might have been more obvious early on.